# creating a qtip with ajax contents based on computed uri params

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I have a link like so

```
<a href="" id="permalink">permalink</a>
```

to which I have bound a qtip2 like so

```
$("#permalink").qtip({
    content: {
        text: "Loading...",
        ajax: {
            url: "http://server/app",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                "uri": $(this).attr("href")
            },
            success: function(data, status) {
                this.set(data);
            }
        }
    }
})
.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The href is updated dynamically by some other code (actually, the permalink control in OpenLayers). If I click on the permalink in the absence of qtip, I get the right href. However, with qtip, $(this).attr("href") gets nothing. It is unset. How can I get qtip to receive the dynamically computed href?

Answer (score 2):

Use "each()". You should have the correct scope for $(this) then...

```
$("#permalink").each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: "Loading...",
            ajax: {
                url: "http://server/app",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    "uri": $(this).attr("href")
                },
                success: function(data, status) {
                  this.set('content.text', data);
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the above solution works fine but with the following changes.
I have verified this latest stable release (v2.0.1).

*Instead of*  `this.set(data);`
*use*
`this.set('content.text', data);`